# Remove non-duplicated rows from pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is rather simple but I can't get me head around it. Let's say for the following data frame, I want to keep only the rows with duplicated values in column y:

```
>>> df
   x  y
    x   y
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   2
3   4   3
4   5   3
5   6   3
6   7   5
7   8   2
```

The desired output looks like:

```
>>> df
    x   y
1   2   2
2   3   2
3   4   3
4   5   3
5   6   3
7   8   2
```

I tried this:

```
df[~df.duplicated('y')]
```

but I get this:

```
    x   y
0   1   1
1   2   2
3   4   3
6   7   5
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

> keep : {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’
>
> - first : Mark
>     duplicates as True except for the first occurrence.
> - last : Mark
>     duplicates as True except for the last occurrence.
> - **False : Mark all
>     duplicates as True.**

Meaning you are looking for:

```
df[df.duplicated('y',keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
    x   y
1   2   2
2   3   2
3   4   3
4   5   3
5   6   3
7   8   2
```