# Pandas select first x rows corresponding to y values, removing results below x

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

```
ID A B
0  7 4
0  5 2
0  0 3
1  6 7
1  8 9
2  5 5
```

I would like to select the first x rows for all `IDs`, but only with there are more than rows for those `IDs` like so:

If x == 2:

```
ID A B
0  7 4
0  5 2
1  6 7
1  8 9
```

If x == 3:

```
ID A B
0  7 4
0  5 2
0  0 3
```

... and so on.

Using `df.groupby("ID").head(2)` approximates what I want, but includes the first row for `ID "2"`, which I don't want:

```
ID A B
0  7 4
0  5 2
1  6 7
1  8 9
2  5 5
```

Is there an efficient way to do that, without having to resort to counting rows for each `ID`?

Comment: `df.groupby("ID").head(2)` then [remove the loners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526985/remove-non-duplicated-rows-from-pandas)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it well. Your solution would work in the narrow case I described, but I should've been more generic: the "2" isn't necessarily a fixed "2", it's a threshold, and I want to remove all those with less than the threshold.
So, if it's "3" instead, I want there to only be the rows concerning ID "0", since only 0 has 3+ rows. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False`:

```
v = df.groupby('ID').head(2)
v[v.ID.duplicated(keep=False)]

   ID  A  B
0   0  7  4
1   0  5  2
3   1  6  7
4   1  8  9
```

---

You could also do a 2x `groupby` (nah... wouldn't recommend):

```
df[df.groupby('ID').ID.transform('size').gt(1)].groupby('ID').head(2)

   ID  A  B
0   0  7  4
1   0  5  2
3   1  6  7
4   1  8  9
```

Comment: Thanks, your second suggestion fits, as it can be generalised to values other than 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
x = 2
gr = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)\
    .apply(lambda grp: grp.head(x) if len(grp) >= x else None)\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

The lambda function applied here checks whether the group length
is at least `x` (a kind of filtration on group lenght)
and for such groups outputs the first `x` rows.

This way you avoid the second `groupby`.

The result is:

```
   ID  A  B
0   0  7  4
1   0  5  2
2   1  6  7
3   1  8  9
```